# How likely is it for a hard disk to fail, on using it every day in a bus going on a bumpy road for 3 hours?

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive

I have installed ubuntu in my old laptop, and am thinking to use it in the bus, while going to or coming back from, college.

This laptop is around 5 years old. And even it has the notification of "Self test failed" notification in the disks app of ubuntu.

Can my hard disk work for at least one year, on using laptop for around 3 hours every day, in a bus going on a bumpy road?

**Edit:**

To be precise, on average, how many vibrations can hd handle, before getting failed?

On typing `smartctl -q noserial -a /dev/sda`in the terminal, I have got this below text:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-22-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Seagate Samsung SpinPoint M8 (AF)
Device Model:     ST500LM012 HN-M500MBB
Firmware Version: 2AR10002
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Form Factor:      2.5 inches
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 6
SATA Version is:  SATA 2.6, 3.0 Gb/s
Local Time is:    Mon Jun  4 12:33:00 2018 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED
See vendor-specific Attribute list for marginal Attributes.

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      ( 121) The previous self-test completed having
                    the read element of the test failed.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        ( 6840) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x51) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    No Auto Offline data collection support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 114) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   100   100   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       4566
  2 Throughput_Performance  0x0027   252   252   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0023   091   091   025    Pre-fail  Always       -       2862
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   086   086   000    Old_age   Always       -       14637
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   252   252   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x002f   252   252   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  8 Seek_Time_Performance   0x0025   252   252   015    Pre-fail  Offline      -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       12478
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0033   252   252   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 11 Calibration_Retry_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       120
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   092   092   000    Old_age   Always       -       8875
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0022   077   077   000    Old_age   Always       -       509761983
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0032   252   252   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0033   252   252   048    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
186 Unknown_Attribute       0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       1348
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0002   059   036   040    Old_age   Always   In_the_past 41 (Min/Max 22/65)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0022   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       489
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0022   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   089   089   000    Old_age   Always       -       113540
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0002   059   036   000    Old_age   Always       -       41 (Min/Max 22/65)
195 Hardware_ECC_Recovered  0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
196 Reallocated_Event_Count 0x0032   252   252   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0032   252   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0030   252   252   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x0036   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
200 Multi_Zone_Error_Rate   0x002a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       32640
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      9489         13860224
# 2  Extended offline    Completed: read failure       90%      8600         13860224
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      8600         -
# 4  Short offline       Completed: read failure       90%      5315         59774495
# 5  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      4607         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 0
Note: revision number not 1 implies that no selective self-test has ever been run
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Completed_read_failure [90% left] (0-65535)
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: Technically, what you asked is an opinion-based question that nobody can answer.  However, there isn't likely to be disagreement on the "real answer", which you probably already suspect.  It's already starting to fail, which means that you should consider it failed and replace it while you're still lucky enough to be able to get your files off of it.

Comment: I would replace the disk as soon as possible. If the system is being used in rough conditions, I'd strongly recommend using an SSD. Also, as Bob mentioned in his answer, taking advantage of cloud storage services to keep your data backed up is a great idea considering that you're a student.

Comment: Hi, didn't see the new edit in the answer below. Now, new edit of the answer below seems to be answering my question; I have accepted it as the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the drive has failed a [SMART](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S.M.A.R.T.) self-test, I would back up all data and replace it as soon as possible. At this stage, it's possible that the disk has already suffered from bad sectors, and existing data on the drive may be corrupted.

To help us better determine the condition of the hard drive, try running `smartctl -q noserial -a /dev/sda` as root (replace `/dev/sda` if necessary) and adding the output to your post. (The `-q noserial` hides the serial number and WWN of your drive.)

Considering that hard drives are shock-sensitive, I'd strongly recommend replacing it with an SSD. SSDs have no moving parts, use less power, and are much faster than electromechanical hard drives.

---

Your SMART data looks quite peculiar:

- The only failed attribute is temperature; the drive had previously overheated, having reached 65 °C, but otherwise looks okay. (The normal operating temperature range for most modern hard drives is 5-60 °C.)
- No sectors have been reallocated. A failing hard drive will often have a nonzero raw value for this attribute.
- The failed SMART test was some 3,000 operating hours ago.
- Attribute 187, Reported Uncorrectable Errors, has a raw value of 1348. This is a sign of trouble; cloud backup and storage provider Backblaze [found this to be a very strong predictor of eventual failure](https://www.backblaze.com/blog/what-smart-stats-indicate-hard-drive-failures/).

Despite the atypical SMART information provided by the drive, it does look like failure is imminent. Back up all data and replace the drive as soon as possible.

---

To answer the question as worded:

- The [specifications for your hard drive](https://www.seagate.com/files/www-content/support-content/internal-products/spinpoint-m-series/en-us/100698122f.pdf) state that it can tolerate a maximum shock of 350 G during operation. Shock in excess of this limit can result in damage to the drive, and this is *not* a difficult threshold to exceed; for more information, see [this Physics Stack Exchange question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/188673/what-would-put-a-harddisk-drive-hdd-under-350gs-of-force). The hard drive also has a maximum vibration spec of 1.5 Grms, which is *very* easily exceeded on a bumpy bus ride. It is generally not a matter of how many shocks the drive takes; instead, it is one of how hard they are.
- SSDs contain no moving parts and are therefore not easily damaged by shock and vibration. In most cases, it would take a hard direct blow to actually cause damage to an SSD. With hard drives, even a short drop to the floor can result in failure (see Physics question linked above).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am new to ubuntu. I typed the text you gave, it asked me to install packages via other text, then in between the installation of the packages, it is asking for Postfix Cofiguration (Options given to me: No configuration, internet site, internet with smarthost, stellite system, local only). I don't know what to do, after this. :(

Comment: @Immortal: Select "no configuration" unless you need email alerts from smartmontools. This essentially operates by using your system as a mail server, which can be complicated and is generally unnecessary.

Comment: HI, I got this: smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.15.0-22-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

Smartctl open device: /dev/sda failed: Permission denied

Comment: @Immortal: smartctl requires root permissions to function. Be sure to edit your question with the output once you get it to work.

Comment: Sorry, how do I give the permission?

Comment: Prefix the command with `sudo` and enter your password.

Comment: Hi, I have edited the question now.

Comment: Thank you for the edit. I have everything in OneDrive; I am thinking to use it as long as it works, and then when it dies, I am thinking to buy SSD and install ubuntu. Is there any problem in this way? Is there any way to say on average, for how many days my hd would work on using it bus or not using it in bus?

Comment: I would *not* be able to predict when failure might occur. I'd just replace it as soon as possible.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Why not use it till it dies (if everything is in the cloud), instead of replacing now itself?

Answer (score 3):

It will fail tomorrow. Or maybe next week. Or maybe in ten years.

There is no reliable way to predict hard drive failure.

**Make sure you have an up-to-date backup copy of anything you cannot afford to lose.** This is the **only** thing you can do to defend against hard drive failure. You **will**, at some point, lose everything up till your most recent backup.

If we're talking about schoolwork, it's often better to keep those synced to remote ("cloud") storage, e.g. OneDrive, Google Drive, Dropbox, etc.. That way, you'll only lose up till the last time you had an internet connection.

---

All that said, I personally wouldn't even bother using a drive that has S.M.A.R.T. failure indications. Chuck it in the bin and get a new drive; it's not worth the time spent on recovery later.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am using the laptop only for internet, and for online ms office. Everything is in onedrive. Do you know on how much vibrations hd can handle before getting failed?

Answer (score 3):

Buy a SSD and be worryless. It's not sensitive to all the physical "interactions" you're concerned with here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. SSD's are costly for me now, will think on it.

Comment: @ImmortalPlayer Take another look. You might be surprised. Entry-level SSDs have prices comparable to hard disks.

Comment: Didn't know that, will check back again. Thank you.

Comment: Keeping in mind that SSDs still can and will fail, even if not due to environmental factors. As always, back up anything important.

Comment: @Bob Totally agree on backing up anything important, also, you can always start using cloud services as well, use their offline version when you've got no internet and they'll be automatically saved on the server as soon as you have a connection.